# How do I copy the directory and its folders in windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

*Windows environment*:

I am having some difficulties with doing what I expected to be rather simple.
I have for the past 2 hours been unable to copy a directory and its files and sub-directories to another location.

**e.g.:** I have Directory MyDir with files 01.txt 02.txt and a Sub-Directory MyDir2 with files sd01.txt inside it.

I have been trying to use the commands ROBOCOPY as well as XCOPY. Here are 2 examples of the commands I have tried.

`>ROBOCOPY /MIR MyDir temp`

`>ROBOCOPY /MIR /CREATE MyDir temp`

What happens is the only the files and directories that are inside of MyDir are being copied.

What I want is for the folder MyDir itself to be copied to temp.

What is incorrect about my syntax?

Comment: Answer below from Marged: `robocopy /mir /create mydir temp\mydir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XCOPY this would do the job:

```
xcopy mydir temp\mydir /s /i
```

If `mydir` is missing below `temp` it will be created as a directory (`/i`).
`/s` copies subdirectories

You might want to mix any of the parameters xcopy offers, for example `/e`, `/k` - but this depends on what exactly you need to do besides copying the directory structure and files.

Using `temp\mydir` as the target will work for robocopy too:

```
robocopy /mir /create mydir temp\mydir
```

Tried both commands here and they worked for me.

Comment: This helped as I was not aware I had to tell it for the destination the same name folder as I was copying. I expected it to be created on its own.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcopy DIRSOURCE DIRDESTINATION /s /e /h
```

DIRSOURCE = the path to the directory being copied

DIRDESTINATION = the path to where you would like to copy DIRSOURCE

/s : Copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty

/e : Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty

/h : Copies files with hidden and system file attributes